# Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 647, 1335 and precision: 16, 16'

Tags: automation, ui-automation, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

Espresso is unable to perform any action on the app at the right corner of any device.It throws below error.

I have tried below code:

```
onView(withId(R.id.mapHomeSearch)).perform(click());
```

I have also tested it with closing the keyboard, scrolling, position, descendant, etc. But the error remains the same of every app icon falling in that co-ordinates.

Any help would be appreciated.

> android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing
>   'single click - At Coordinates: 647, 1335 and precision: 16, 16' on
>   view 'with 0 child view of type parentMatcher'.

Answer (score 2):

Before performing any test make sure you have off the following option on both physical or emulator:

- Window animation scale
- Transition animation scale
- Animator duration scale

After that:

You need to close your soft key before performing any other click.

For example:

`onView(withId(R.id.info_input)).perform(typeText("xxxxxx"), ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard());`  //this close function from support library.

Otherwise the the soft keyboard blocked the screen and it blocks button clicking later.